# Hosting ASP.NET site in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I was hosting published site in IIS 7 on Windows 7 installed machine. 
I had done setting for .NET framework version, Security Options but got Error as shown below

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server
>   Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed
>   because the related configuration data
>   for the page is invalid.  Detailed
>   Error Information Module IIS Web Core 
>   Notification BeginRequest
>
> Handler Not yet determined
>
> Error Code 0x800700b7
>
> Config Error There is a duplicate
>   'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler'
>   section defined
>
> Config File
>   \?\D:\inetpub\wwwroot\KDAHCSSD\web.config
>
> Requested URL
>   http://localhost:80/KDAHCSSD/frmLogin.aspx
>
> Physical Path
>   D:\inetpub\wwwroot\KDAHCSSD\frmLogin.aspx
>
> Logon Method Not yet determined
>
> Logon User Not yet determined
>
> Config Source    13:
>   sectionGroup name="scripting"
>   type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup,
>   System.Web.Extensions,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
>
> 14:      section
>   name="scriptResourceHandler"
>   type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection,
>   System.Web.Extensions,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
>   requirePermission="false"
>   allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/
>
> 15:         sectionGroup
>   name="webServices"
>   type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup,
>   System.Web.Extensions,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
>
> Links and More InformationThis error
>   occurs when there is a problem reading
>   the configuration file for the Web
>   server or Web application. In some
>   cases, the event logs may contain more
>   information about what caused this
>   error.
>
> View more information »

How to solve this. What will I need to do?..

Comment: Are you running a .Net 4 Framework ASP .Net website?

Comment: No I am running .NET 3.5 Framework Site and have selected the proper version in IIS.

Comment: Have you tried removing the offending lines from your web.config?

Comment: I am Trying for that.n Will tell you

Comment: Site is browsed. Removed offending lines. Now solving Database Access problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running a .Net 4 site, the machine.config will already have defined the `scriptResourceHandler`. Remove this section from the web.config and you should be fine.
EDIT: Just noticed you say you are running 3.5 and so shouldn't happen, but try removing that section and see if it works.

Comment: Now Getting Error about "jsonSerialization" .. Shall I remove also that?

Comment: I don't know...What is the error for this? If it's the same then I would advise trying it, and any further ones as they are most likely in the machine.config, but maybe backup your web.config file first.

Comment: Site is browsed. Removed offending lines. Now solving Database Access problem. Thank you For Answer

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if your application is compiled against the .NET 2.0 CLR and you're trying to run it in a .NET 4.0/4.5 application pool.

If that's the case (as it was for me), switching to the correct app pool solves the problem.